# How to change API Gateway's deployment version of current stage with aws cli or sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

As stated in the question's title, I want to change deployment version of current stage in AWS API Gateway.
It can be easily achieved via the web console, but I cannot figure out how to make it via cli/sdk. 
Could anybody kindly tell me whether it is possible or not? If it is, which API or command could I use?
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-deployment.html

Comment: @RaGe Hi, actually I tried this command, but failed. Could you tell me what `patch-operations` should be used?

Comment: did you see the example posted on that page?

Comment: @RaGe Sure. It was an example to show how to replace the description with a new one, but I still can not figure out how to switch deployment by using this command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
aws apigateway update-stage --stage-name <stage> --rest-api-id <rest-api-id> 
    --patch-operations "op=replace,path=/deploymentId,value=<deployment-id>"
```

Comment: In fact, it is the command I tried first but get error output. I retried it again after switching my environment from MinGW to CentOS and then succeed. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer!